# How to use apt to force remove corrupting package?

Tags: apt, 20.04

I got the following error message:

```
$ sudo apt -f remove libgranite-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgranite5 : Depends: libgranite-common (>= 5.3.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgranite6 : Depends: libgranite-common (>= 6.0.0+r2017+pkg118~daily~ubuntu6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgranite-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgranite-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/53.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 364127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgranite-common_6.0.0+r2017+pkg118~daily~ubuntu6.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgranite-common (6.0.0+r2017+pkg118~daily~ubuntu6.1) over (5.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite-common_6.0.0+r2017+pkg118~daily~ubuntu6.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite5:amd64 5.3.0-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite-common_6.0.0+r2017+pkg118~daily~ubuntu6.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Whoa, hang on. A "*broken*" package is NOT corrupt. It's "broken" in the sense that it "breaks" a clean solution. Your output clearly shows that you are trying to install packages that conflict with each other...which has no clean solution ("breaks"). The output even shows you *exactly* why those packages conflict.

Answer (score 2):

libgranite5 and libgranite6 depend on the libgranite-common package which uses the same file as another package. First, try to `apt -f remove libgranite{5,6}`.

Then, you may need to only install one version of the library in the future.